# Which hook is fired when tag is added or changed?

Tags: taxonomy, hooks, tags, transient

I have a [transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) that collects WordPress tags with specific description.

I'm looking for a hook name that fires when user edits a WordPress tag or creates a new tag in admin so I can delete my transient and create a new one from updated tags.